# PHP, Array result in table format in a sequence

Tags: php, html-table

I'm using below coding to get an array result in a table,

```
$presents = @json_decode(fBGetDataStore('presents'), true);
foreach ($presents as $key=>$value){
     $icon = $_SESSION['data']->table('units')->byCode($value['itemCode'])->data();   
     $i = 1;
echo '<table border=1 class="sortable" align="center">
<tr>
<td class="sortable" align="center">#</td>
<td class="sortable" align="center">Sender IMG</td>
<td class="sortable" align="center">Sender ID</td>
<td class="sortable" align="center">Item Code</td>
<td class="sortable" align="center">IMG</td>
</tr>';
    echo '<tr><td align="center">'.$i++.'</td>';
    echo '<td>&nbsp;<img src="http://graph.facebook.com/'. $value['sender'] .'/picture" width="70" height="50"&nbsp;</td>';
    echo '<td align="center">'. $value['sender'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td align="center">'. $value['itemCode'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td><img src="http://static-0.farmville.zgncdn.com/assets/hashed/' . fBImageGetHash($icon['iconname']). '" width=45px height=45px ></td>' ;
    echo '</tr>';
}
```

and also I'm getting a table but I want to count `#` of results in a sequence because right now my results are showing in many more than one tables which contain only one row.

I'm getting as a result :

[image: http://prntscr.com/6vrjlg]

Comment: you need to write your table and name column code outside of foreach loop thats it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just tested the 1st and 2nd answer (by both of them you will get `1` means same figure as `#` column so my opinion is you should use to count rows :

```
$presents = @json_decode(fBGetDataStore('presents'), true);

$i = 1;
// Table starting 
echo '<table border=1 class="sortable" align="center">
<tr>
<td class="sortable" align="center">#</td>
<td class="sortable" align="center">Sender IMG</td>
<td class="sortable" align="center">Sender ID</td>
<td class="sortable" align="center">Item Code</td>
<td class="sortable" align="center">IMG</td>
</tr>';

foreach ($presents as $key=>$value){
   $icon = $_SESSION['data']->table('units')->byCode($value['itemCode'])->data();   

echo '<tr><td align="center">'.$i++.'</td>';
echo '<td>&nbsp;<img src="http://graph.facebook.com/'. $value['sender'] .'/picture" width="70" height="50"&nbsp;</td>';
echo '<td align="center">'. $value['sender'] . '</td>';
echo '<td align="center">'. $value['itemCode'] . '</td>';
echo '<td><img src="http://static-0.farmville.zgncdn.com/assets/hashed/' . fBImageGetHash($icon['iconname']). '" width=45px height=45px ></td>' ;
echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>'; //Table end
```

i hope you will get it as your need.

Comment: this is a fail ... why do you run foreach twice ? ```foreach ($num as $cnt) ``` and from where did you take these variables from as they not appear to be on the main question ?

Comment: @Danny in your answer " here you should use `$i = 1;` out of foreach loop otherwise questioner will get `# 1` in column instead counting rows "

Comment: double fail ... you editted your post and then you answered me .. you understood you had a problem.. next time just admit.

(why I have a feelings that its a fake question and a fake answer ?? maybe because of the poster name)

Comment: i think correction is better in own answer to provide our best knowledge to others and tell me one thing .. have you checked your answer before posting ? that is absolute right for answer or not ?

Answer (score 3):

```
echo '<table border=1 class="sortable" align="center">
<tr>
<td class="sortable" align="center">#</td>
<td class="sortable" align="center">Sender IMG</td>
<td class="sortable" align="center">Sender ID</td>
<td class="sortable" align="center">Item Code</td>
<td class="sortable" align="center">IMG</td>
</tr>';

$presents = @json_decode(fBGetDataStore('presents'), true);
foreach ($presents as $key=>$value){
  $icon = $_SESSION['data']->table('units')->byCode($value['itemCode'])->data();   
  $i = 1;
  echo '<tr><td align="center">'.$i++.'</td>';
  echo '<td>&nbsp;<img src="http://graph.facebook.com/'. $value['sender'] .'/picture" width="70" height="50"&nbsp;</td>';
  echo '<td align="center">'. $value['sender'] . '</td>';
  echo '<td align="center">'. $value['itemCode'] . '</td>';
  echo '<td><img src="http://static-0.farmville.zgncdn.com/assets/hashed/' . fBImageGetHash($icon['iconname']). '" width=45px height=45px ></td>' ;
  echo '</tr>';
}
```

you need to print the table outside of loop, so only the relevent row will repeat itself.